# MAUI Speech Recognition - Unable to Store Final Result of a Processed Speech When SpeechInputCompleteSilence Intent Is Enabled

Tags: android, maui, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm using Gerald Versluis method to enable Speech Recognition and Speech-To-Text on Android using MAUI - [https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiSpeechToTextSample](https://stackoverflow.com)

I'm trying to make the Recognition Text permanent by moving it to another label and so it doesn't get overwritten by new incoming speech, but I can't seem to access the value that holds the final processed speech.

In the RecordButton method, the value that contains the final recognized speech is RecognitionText. From MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    private async void RecordButton()
    {
        var isAuthorized = await speechToText.RequestPermissions();

        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            try
            {
                RecognitionText = await speechToText.Listen(
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                    new Progress<string>(partialText =>
                    {
                        RecognitionText = partialText;
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RecognitionText));
                    }),
                    tokenSource.Token);

// When ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis is used, this code is never reached
// When ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis is commented out, this code is reached and everything works great
                HistoryText += RecognitionText + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HistoryText));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Permission Error", "No microphone access", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Here's the XAML part from MainPage.xaml

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border>
            <ScrollView Margin="10">
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    x:Name="HistoryLabel"
                    Text="{Binding HistoryText}"
                    FontSize="{OnIdiom Phone=Medium, Tablet=Large}" />
            </ScrollView>
        </Border>
        <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="RecognitionLabel"
            Text="{Binding RecognitionText}"
            FontSize="{OnIdiom Phone=Medium, Tablet=Large}"
            Margin="5"
            Padding="5" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            CornerRadius="60"
            WidthRequest="120"
            HeightRequest="120"
            Text="Record"
            FontSize="24"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            Command="{Binding RecordButtonCommand}" />

    </Grid>
```

This is the Listen method definition in SpeechToTextImplementation.cs

```
        public async Task<string> Listen(CultureInfo culture, IProgress<string> recognitionResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var taskResult = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

            listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener
            {
                Error = ex => taskResult.TrySetException(new Exception("Failure in speech engine - " + ex)),
                PartialResults = sentence =>
                {
                    recognitionResult?.Report(sentence);
                },
                Results = sentence => taskResult.TrySetResult(sentence)
            };

            speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(Android.App.Application.Context);

            if (speechRecognizer is null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Speech recognizer is not available.");

            speechRecognizer.SetRecognitionListener(listener);
            speechRecognizer.StartListening(CreateSpeechIntent(culture));

            await using (cancellationToken.Register(() =>
            {
                StopRecording();
                taskResult.TrySetCanceled();
            }))
            {
                return await taskResult.Task;
            }
        }
```

And finally the CreateSpeechIntent method with the problem intent

```
        private static Intent CreateSpeechIntent(CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
            intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguagePreference, Java.Util.Locale.Default);

            var javaLocale = Java.Util.Locale.ForLanguageTag(culture.Name);
            intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, javaLocale);
            intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
            intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraCallingPackage, Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName);

//-->Problem//intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 10000);

            //intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraBiasingStrings, ...) // SCA Use ATC strings!!
            //intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
            //intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            //intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000); // SCA Are you done talking? Yes or no. Set right ere.

            intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPartialResults, true);

            return intent;
        }
```

- Commenting out intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 10000); fixes the problem. Unfortunately, I need to leave the mic open for 10 seconds.
- I used different values for ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, but any value I use causes the problem. This is for debugging only, since I need the full 10 secs.
- I tried to access *RecognitionText* from SpeecToTextImplementation.cs, but no matter what I tried the UI would not update with the value sent. SpeecToTextImplementation.cs is in the Android folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was easily resolved by simply using the MAUI Community Toolkit. The MCT has all the needed methods to handle speech processing. There is no longer a need to do it manually. Just use the toolkit's RecognitionResultUpdated and RecognitionResultCompleted to get the partial and final result.